# 1x4 Button membrane help

Tags: button

Im trying out [this membrane](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1332?gclid=CjwKEAjw7aiwBRCPgdu70arX70wSJADK6iDD89H4xAIdw88_bv9K8EcrhdbdzERDU0gKJgrRwAcO2xoClM_w_wcB) from Adafruit that i bought last week but i have a little issue. ITS SO SENSITIVE! i as so just touch it with my finger and it transmits!. Anyone that has worked with this membrane have the same issue? is there some sort of "fix"?

**UPDATE**

Its really simple. But one weird thing, not sure if its supposed to be like that, but by default, the buttons are on `HIGH`. i used `Serial.println(digitalRead(one));` to verify that and the output was 1.

```
int two =  8;
int one = 9;
int four = 10;
int three = 11;

void setup() {
  pinMode(one, INPUT);
  pinMode(two, INPUT);
  pinMode(three, INPUT);
  pinMode(four, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if(digitalRead(one) == LOW){
    Serial.println("One");
  }else if(digitalRead(two) == LOW){
    Serial.println("Two");
  }else if(digitalRead(three) == LOW){
    Serial.println("Three");
  }else if(digitalRead(four) == LOW){
    Serial.println("Four");
  }
}
```

Comment: You have the pullups enabled on the 4 pins, right?

Comment: Please show your code and wiring.

Comment: [This is my setup](http://i.imgur.com/yVoS9US.jpg) and my code will updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> pinMode(one, INPUT);
> ```

You have configured the input with no pullup. Since it is a CMOS input and hence very high impedance, it effectively acts as an antenna picking up random signals including that of your finger becoming capacitively coupled to it. You *must* enable the pullup on the pins (and connect the common to ground) if you want correct operation.

```
 pinMode(one, INPUT_PULLUP);
```

Comment: i was not aware of such a thing, thanks! Im quite new to arduino